# Which head piece would be the cheapest?

Tags: minifigures, shopping

I would like to fill a vase with LEGO heads to decorate my living room so I am looking for the best option to buy bulk heads.

I have been looking at Bricklink but I can't find a good way to tell. I want 200 (not sure about the number for the moment) yellow heads, don't mind what the face painted looks like but I want to find the cheapest option.

Has anybody got any clue on the best way to do that?

Comment: Not really suited as a permanent answer, so posting as a comment. This vendor on EBay sells lots of 50 heads for $20.99, with free shipping on orders over $50: http://www.ebay.com/itm/LEGO-Minifigure-Heads-Assorted-Faces-City-Town-Alien-Skull-Yellow-Bulk-Lot-/331103363748. You might want to message him and see if he can give you an all-yellow head lot for (e.g. 200 for $75 or something like that).

Comment: Also not a permanent answer, so I will just comment. BrickLink is really good for finding individual parts, but it is not so good for bulk ordering. As Phil mentioned, it would be better to look for bulk head lots on eBay. If you do want to shop on BrickLink, I would suggest that you post on the BrickLink forum about your project, and let sellers make you offers. Common heads should really not be more than 10 cents a piece (this applies to the US).

Comment: Thanks for this hint, I have tried to write some code to get data from Bricklink and it appears, if you don't mind about the new/used status of the head, there are option to get them for ~15 cents in Europe, I have not been able to find better option on ebay there at the moment, I will post on this thread when my search is over.

Comment: Do they all have to be the same head print or the same? Also have you considered cheating and filling up the centre of the vase with padding so that you need fewer heads?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this on Bricklink is to run an [advanced search](http://www.bricklink.com/searchAdvanced.asp) over the "Minifig, Head" category. Here's [an example](http://www.bricklink.com/search.asp?viewFrom=sa&qMin=200&itemType=P&catID=238&colorID=3&searchSort=C&sz=100) showing all yellow parts in this category with a minimum lot size of 200 sorted by price, lowest first.

This shows you the cheapest stores to order 200 of the same yellow head from. If you want a little variety, I'm sure those sellers have other heads available as well.